# EventListener beforeunload and JavaScript global variable

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a SpringBoot/JSP/JavaScript application and I'm trying to trigger the **beforeunload** browser popup message only when the command to change page doesn't come from within the application itself, when it comes from the browser (back, forward, refresh, home, etc.)

So every time a button in the app is clicked I

1. set the **actionFromApp** JavaScript global variable to **true** (variable which is set by default to **false** every time the page is refreshed)
2. disable all the buttons in the page
3. submit the form

I'm 100% sure the global variable is set properly, there's no way for the app to disable buttons and submit the form without setting it to true. But randomly the beforeunload event listener seems not to detect it: this happens on every button, sometimes immediately on the first click on the page, some other times after a few clicks.

How is this possible?

My code:

**Variable declaration at the top of my JS file**

```
let actionFromApp = false;
```

**onButtonClick**

```
function buttonClick(formName) {
   setActionFromApp();
   disableAllActiveButtons(formName);
   document.getElementById(formName).submit();
}
```

**SetActionFromApp**

```
function setActionFromApp() {
   actionFromApp = true;
}
```

**EventListener**

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
   if (!actionFromApp) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = true;
   }
});
```

I know the EventListener works just fine when I remove the *if* clause or if I set it just to true.

Cheers.

Comment: What does the `actionFromApp` return? We need the code to point out what's wrong.

Comment: And what do you store in it? Did you set this variable yourself somewhere in your code? And if you did, include this variable in your post so we can check out what it stores.

Comment: What do you mean by "What does the actionFromApp return?"? `actionFromApp` is the global variable.
Unfortunately I can't inspect the variable in the EventListener function as alerts are not allowed there, but in my tests I triggered an alert soon after setting the variable and it was indeed **true**

Comment: I've edited my question, the variable is just a global variable I've created at the top of my JS file

Comment: That helped a lot, it's more clear now. If you set your variable to `true` everytime the user presses/clicks a button, doesn't that mean that your condition will be `false`?

Comment: Correct: if the action doesn't come from the app itself then trigger the `beforeunload` popup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222238/discussion-between-vmank-and-fleales).